# Force a function to report argument type mismatches

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, syntax, debugging

As a relative newcomer to *Mathematica*, I am still frequently caught out by coding errors that, at least by default, MMA does not indicate to the front end, in particular when I define a function and the argument types and then accidentally pass an argument of the wrong type.

For example, if I define

`f[x_Integer] := x + 1;`

and then call

`f[{1}]`

it is returned unevaluated because {1} has Head "List" and "Integer" is required.

This sort of thing tends to happen to me when I first test a larger and more complex function where other errors are to be expected, in which case my attention usually goes directly to the code.

**Question**: How can I write functions and declare the argument types on which the rest of the code may depend and let MMA tell me when I have passed an argument of the wrong kind?

Comment: `Compile` your function, and you will get what you want, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to write a function with argument checking is to write subroutines for your function `f` that handles the actual calculation, and then do the argument checking in the main routine for `f`.

As a highly simplified example, let's call the subroutines for `f` `intF`:

```
intF[x_Integer] := x + 1
intF[x_ /; ArrayQ[x, _, IntegerQ]] := x + 1
```

so that `f` should only work for an integer or an array of integers.

We can then define error messages that `f` can emit:

```
f::nlst = "The argument `1` is not an integer or an array of integers.";
```

From that, you can write `f` like this:

```
f[x__] := Module[{nargs, res},
  nargs = Length[{x}];
  res /; If[nargs == 1, 
            If[Head[res = intF[x]] =!= intF,
               True,
               Message[f::nlst, x]; False],
            Message[f::argx, f, nargs]; False]]
```

The main point here is the use of `Condition[]` (`/;`) to do the argument checking; recall that in the expression `expr /; test`, `test` should be something that evaluates to `True` or `False`, and `expr` will only then be evaluated.

In this example, the first check is a simple argument count, done by checking if `{x}` has length 1 (i.e. `f` was only passed one argument). If the test fails, then the part `Message[f::argx, f, nargs]; False` gets evaluated, and since the last result is `False`, we get no evaluation of `res`.

Note, however, that I did not define the message `f::argx`. In this case, the message text is taken from `General::argx`.

If the check of the argument count is passed, we get to the inner conditional. In there, we evaluate `Head[res = intF[x]] =!= intF`. Two things are done here: the result of the subroutine `intF[x]` is assigned to `res`, after which it is checked if evaluation occurred (i.e. the head of `res` is no longer `intF`). If this test is passed, we get the ultimate result `True` for the condition, and thus the previously evaluated `res` is returned. Otherwise, `Message[f::nlst, x]; False` gets evaluated.

With this, `f[3]` and `f[{{1}, {2}}]` will evaluate as usual, but `f[2.]` and `f[{{5, 6}, {4}}]` will throw the message `f::nlst`, while `f[1, 9]` will throw the message `f::argx`.

Comment: Very nice & clear exposition, thx! Question though: the head check tests evaluation so doesn't say anything specific (just like seeing the fn unevaluated in output) & the message f::nlst seems to assume that evaluation did not occur because of the mismatch - but what if evaluation failed because of a coding error rather than an argument mismatch? I don't know MMA well enough to know whether that is actually possible, but I *think* I recall function definitions that seem to be OK (the symbol gets defined on shift-return) but don't evaluate even with correct arguments. Or am I mis-remembering?

Comment: PS Part of my Q is really - when MMA checks arguments and finds a mismatch, why doesn't it report that itself?

Comment: I'll try to write additional details later, but to quickly answer your second question: *Mathematica* is allowing for the possibility that you might write additional definitions later. Using the `f` example, if I add a third definition for `intF` that covers input not covered by the previous definitions, then `f` gets to use that definition as well.

Comment: You are most kind; but if MMA is checking against all symbols is an unevaluated output *defined* to mean no matching symbol definition - and any other error in e.g. code is always indicated some other way?

Comment: "...if *Mathematica* is checking against all symbols, is an unevaluated output defined to mean no matching symbol definition" - it is, first and foremost, a pattern-matching language; it will do something only if it has been *explicitly* told how to handle objects that match a defined pattern. So, in the `intF` case, I told *Mathematica* how it should deal with integer input in one definition, and how to handle an array of integers in a second definition. Any other thing not matching those two defined patterns is left unevaluated.

Comment: So if it does match it is evaluated but the evaluation may fail, which is separately notified; got it. Thx.